# Isotope - reLayout on container width change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

My container is 800px. This space is occupied with the portfolio container. When then button is clicked to enable the filter menu then the portfolio container is told to have a width of 610px which leaves the remainder of the space for the filter menu. I am using the reLayout call to try and update the items but it only seems to work when the filters menu is disabled. Can anyone see where I am going wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

See below for the snippet of my button code. View **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/rJxew)** to see all code.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    filtertoggle.toggleClass("filter-active");
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $('button').click(function(){
    filtertoggle.toggleClass("filter-active");
    setTimeout(function(){
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        }, filtertoggle.hasClass("filter-active") ? 100: 755);
  });
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nDmyB

Comment: Ah is that working because the timeout is the amount of time the transition takes?

Comment: http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/mtluH if I change the width then that method doesn't seem to work, can you see why?

Comment: Think I have got it working by changing the 100 value, what does that do?

Comment: http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/mtluH my final pen, sorry for the spamming, cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, new Isotope version changes 'reLayout' option to 'layout'. Change

```
$container.isotope('reLayout');
```

... to ...

```
$container.isotope('layout');
```